# Accidental divisibility sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, factorial

It seems (verified for $n \leq 3 \cdot 10^5$) that when the equation

$$p = n!+1 \bmod{\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}}$$

is satisfied with some $n>1\in\mathbb N$ and $p\in\mathbb P$, it implies $n\in\mathbb P$ as well. The overall feel reminds me of a divisibility sequence like Fibonacci or $2^n-1$, which is the only time I've seen prime values locked to prime indices like that. However, I don't see many other factors being passed along with index factors, which is what I would normally expect.

Note that this applies only to the specific $p$ calculated as above using mod as an operation, and not to any arbitrary $p$ satisfying a congruence.

Can anyone explain why my sequence is behaving this way?

---

Upon reflection I think it has to do with my using Wilson's Theorem in a mangled way, and consequently I'm only getting non-$1$ values near primes and $2p$ semiprimes.

Some Mathematica code to show a table if you like:

```
upperBound = 100;
pretty[n_] := 
  If[Length@# > 1, CenterDot @@ #, First@#] &@
    FactorInteger[n] /. {{b_, 1} :> b, {b_, e_} :> Superscript[b, e]};
boldPrime[n_] := If[IntegerQ[n] && PrimeQ[n], Style[n, Bold, Blue], n];
Grid[Table[{n, boldPrime@pretty@n, 
   boldPrime@pretty@Mod[n! + 1, Plus @@ (n^2 (n + 1)^2/4)]}, {n, 2, 
   upperBound}], Alignment -> Right]
```

---

My updated thoughts:

For all $n>9$, it seems like $p=1$ except in one of three conditions:

1. $n+1$ is prime, in which case $n+1$ divides $p$
2. $n+1$ is an even semiprime, i.e. $2q$ with prime $q$, and in which case $2$ divides $p$
3. $n$ is prime, in which case $p$ may or may not be prime, presumably randomly.

If these are indeed the conditions (and I've verified them through $10^5$, so it seems very likely), that would be sufficient to explain the primality correlation. However, I'm still looking for a cogent explanation for why these particular conditions arise from my equation, and will happily accept an answer that can give me some insight into that.

Comment: When you say "it seems": up to what values of $n$ have you checked it?

Comment: Can we assume that $\ p=(n!+1)\ mod\ \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\ $ and that $\ p\ $ is not an arbitary prime satisfying the congruence ? If not, I doubt the claim is correct.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I think it was 500 confirmed with $n<10^5$, it's solid.

Comment: Let $n=1,p=2$...

Comment: @Peter I only saw that $p$ should be the _least_ positive residue in the comment under Kenta S's answer afterwards. It's not clear from the question text.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the current version of the question is clear. What should "a mod b" mean if not the smallest non-negative number with the desired residue ?

Comment: @Peter This is what I intended. "mod" in the sense of a % in C or Python, the operation you just described.

Comment: The following pari/gp-code can be used to search a counterexample : s=1;for(n=1,10^6,s=s*n;p=lift(Mod(s+1,(n^2*(n+1)^2)/4));if(isprime(p)==1,if(isprime(n)==0,print(n,"  ",p))))

Comment: Upto $\ n=3 \cdot 10^5\ $ , the conjecture is true.

Comment: @Trevor maybe explicitly state that it is the least positive residue since the notation you use is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$41617=8!+1+\frac{8^2(8+1)^2}{4}$$
Yet 41617 is a prime and 8 isn't.

There are no smaller counterexamples as $4!+1+k\frac{4^2(4+1)^2}{4}$ will always be a multiple of $5$ (for any $k$), and $6!+1+k\frac{6^2(6+1)^2}{4}$ will always be a multiple of $7$.

Comment: This answer does not adress to the question. $\ p\ $ is the result of the modulo-calculation and not an arbitary number with an equivalent residue.

Comment: @Peter Well, it did address the question that was asked when I wrote it.

Answer (score -1):

Let $n=9,p=6481.$ $p$ is prime, while $n$ is composite, and

$$6481\equiv 9!+1\pmod{\frac{9^2(9+1)^2}4}$$

Comment: I get $9!+1 \bmod (9^2\cdot 10^2 / 4) = 406$.

Comment: $406\equiv 6481\pmod {2025}$

Comment: As Peter corrected, I should have stated it as an equation and not a congruence, it's been edited to reflect that.

Comment: Please make it more clear.